# Regular Expression for 2 matches

Tags: regex, string

I have data, it's written in 1 line. I wrote a regular expression code `/(ART\D\d{4}(.*)\DAND)/g` but I have a mistake here, it just finds a 1 match that starts from first one ART| and last |AND entry. I want to separate them.

> ART|3613{"currentTime":"2016-02-29
>   20:57:06","chat":{"user":"SERVER","msg":"asd"}}|AND
>   ART|8923{"currentTime":"2016-02-29
>   20:57:06","chat":{"user":"SERVER","msg":"asd"}}|AND

[image]

Comment: Are these on separate lines, they don't look like they're on separate lines. What you're trying to do is a non-greedy match, and that can get a little involved.

Comment: They are in 1 line and i seperate them with space

Comment: You can use: [`/ART\D\d{4}(.*?)\DAND/g`](https://regex101.com/r/jZ7gK9/3)

Comment: @SLI like anubhava said, you need to use the non-greedy operator (.*?) to limit it to the first match, **but** this *will* break if someone passes '|AND' as a `msg` key to whatever you're parsing, I would recommend re-thinking whatever you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the non-greedy version... instead of `(.*)`, use `(.*?)`

Comment: Why the backslash?  You're right though about using non-greedy.

Comment: It's because I'm not good with stackoverflow posting syntax.  I tried it without the backslashes and it left the asterisks out entirely.  I tried backslashes (because I was too lazy to look it up) and it seemed to work, but I guess it didn't.  I didn't even notice it was wrong on the second time.

Comment: Ok.. fixed.  I think.  But, really.. when I did it the first time, the asterisks were missing!  Or I need more meds.

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-greedy operator `.*?`. Or it will **eat** the whole rest of your string.

```
 (ART\D\d{4}(.*?)\DAND)
```

Look here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pN0uW9/1).